# Wordpress - Uploading images is causing a timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, timeout, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to upload an image with Wordpress with a call to the REST API, sometimes it will work, but sometimes I will get an error "curl: (52) Empty reply from server".

I've tried with media_sideload_image() and media_handle_upload(), and with error_logs I can know it's at this function that the code stops running.
In the apache logs, I have this error :  "httpd: time limit exceeded `Operation canceled' @ fatal/cache.c/GetImagePixelCache/1794."
The image is uploaded hough.

I could try to increase the variables in the php.ini, but it seems really weird to me that only one upload is causing a timeout, while the websites are running without issue.

I tried to change the function. tried to trigger a curl in PHP instead of the terminal to be sure it was an issue from the server. I tried to run it locally or in our preprod server.
Nothing really worked.

Edit : exemple of code :

```
function pre_upload_image ($url)
{
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    $id = media_sideload_image( $url, 0, null, 'id' );

    return $id;
}


function pre_import($request = null)
{
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    $error = new WP_Error();

    if(empty($request) ||
        empty($request['token']) ||
        empty($request['miniature']))
    {
        $error->add(400, "Request", array('status' => 400));
        return $error;
    }

    $token = get_option('cmc_liseuse_token_import', '');

    if($request['token'] != $token)
    {
        $error->add(410, "Token", array('status' => 400));
        return $error;
    }

    $idMiniature = pre_upload_image($request['miniature']);

    if(!is_int($idMiniature))
    {
        if(is_wp_error($idMiniature))
        {
            return $idMiniature;
        }

        $error->add(440, "Internal error", array('status' => 400));
        return $error;
    }


    return wp_send_json_success();
}


function pre_api_import($request)
{

    register_rest_route( 'pre/v1', '/import', array(
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
        'callback' => 'pre_import',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    ) );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'pre_api_import' );
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay I've provided it.